# Каковы могут быть последствия обновления python?

Tags: python, ubuntu, python-3.x, opencv, pygame

Как повлияет обновление  *python 3.4.0* до *3.4.2* на ранее установленные модули и библиотеки такие как *opencv*,    *pygame* и тд. в *ubuntu 14.04*?

Comment: Не понимаю, зачем обновлять. Ставьте несколько версий и работайте с виртуальными средами.

Comment: На сколько я понял то opencv при установке компилится для определенной версии python если обновить или установить новую версию то работать не будет.

Answer (score 3):

Никак не повлияет - это минорное обновление. Команда разработчиков python не ломает API/ABI в таких случаях.

Answer (score 0):

как я понимаю, всё перечисленное устанавливалось (и будет устанавливаться) не в виде пакетов из репозитория, а в соответствии с «виндоуз-веем» («скачать бесплатно без смс»).

т.е., никакой автоматики обновлений зависимостей, реализованной в системе пакетного менеджмента, ожидать не стоит.

соответственно, с большой долей вероятности многое из перечисленного просто «перестанет работать», т.е. начнёт возвращать ошибки.

Comment: Для начала стоило бы уточнить у автора, как ставились модули/библиотеки, а не заниматься телепатией.

Comment: @insolor, [номеров версий](http://packages.ubuntu.com/search?keywords=python&searchon=names&exact=1&suite=trusty&section=all) в данном случае вполне достаточно для работы «телепатии». тем более, что ответ начинается с оговорки. на случай сбоя «телепатии».

Comment: не совсем понял. Т.е. под ubuntu 14.04 я не могу просто взять и установить например python3 через apt-get install? Или я неправильно вас понял?

Comment: @insolor, и на это я тоже посмотрел, разумеется, перед «включением телепатии»: [python (<< 2.8)](http://packages.ubuntu.com/trusty/python-opencv)

Comment: @insolor, да, вы правильно поняли. в официально поддерживаемых репозиториях для версии 14.04 нет пакетов с python версии 3 и выше.

Comment: По поводу opencv не могу сказать, а вот по поводу python3.4 вы ошибаетесь: http://packages.ubuntu.com/trusty/python/python3.4

Comment: @insolor, спасибо за уточнение! да, в этом вопросе вы правы. / с упомянутым в вопросе pygame — та же ситуация, что и с opencv: [python (<< 2.8)](http://packages.ubuntu.com/trusty/python-pygame)

Comment: @anlima, разве я дал не исчерпывающий ответ на ваш вопрос «как повлияет…»? -- если у вас есть вопросы по поводу того, как всё это хозяйство обновить, чтобы оно продолжало работать — задавайте их, пожалуйста, с помощью кнопки «задать вопрос» в правом верхнем углу этой страницы.

Comment: @alexanderbarakin, вообще-то все пакеты python в windows испокон веков ставятся/обновляются абсолютно так-же как и в других операционных системах - через менеджер пактов питона - pip install <имя пакета> и т.п.. Что бы установить пакет "копи-пастом" где либо, нужно сильно постараться, т.к. большинство пакетов требуют компиляции нативных модулей из исходников и/или препроцессинга py-файлов. По поводу же "ставить в ubuntu всё из системного репозитория" - было замечательно, но многих пакетов там банально нет, либо они устаревшие.

Comment: @SergeyRufanov, я согласен, что разработчики регулярно сталкиваются с ситуациями, когда более приемлемым (для них) оказывается т.н. «windows-way» (pip-ы, cpan-ы, cabal-ы и прочие «make install-ы»). я же не разработчик, а администратор, понимающий все преимущества работы с пакетами и репозиториями (они, кстати, могут быть и локальными, с самостоятельно собранными пакетами). потому, боюсь, вам будет сложно согласиться с моей аргументацией, т.к., судя по всему, вы далеки от задач администрирования чего-то большего, чем «windows-сервер» или «банальный localhost».